# exec-maven-plugin exec:java failing: Cannot assign configuration values to array of type java.lang.String

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

When executing `mvn exec:java` it fails to correctly parse the configuration arguments, throwing the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on
>   project autotest-programmes: Unable to parse configuration of mojo
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java: Cannot assign
>   configuration values to array of type java.lang.String: [-classpath,
>   Classpath {}, --glue, com.company.test.cucumber, --format, pretty,
>   --format, html:C:\workspace\autotest\target] -> [Help 1]

This is the plugin configuration used (using Apache Maven 3.0.3):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
        <executableDependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        </executableDependency>
        <mainClass>cucumber.cli.Main</mainClass>
        <commandlineArgs>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</commandlineArgs>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath/>
            <argument>--glue</argument>
            <argument>com.company.test.cucumber</argument>
            <argument>--format</argument>
            <argument>pretty</argument>
            <argument>--format</argument>
            <argument>html:${project.basedir}\target</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest to remove the empty entries from your configuration and try it again.

```
 <argument>-classpath</argument>
 <classpath/>
```

Cause in java goal the classpath is not allowed based on the [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#arguments).

BTW: Never use "\" in your maven pom. Use forward slashes instead.

Comment: I removed the empty entries and changed the "\" to "/". It moved on from the previous error, however it's now complaining that it cannot find the mainClass. `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project autotest-programmes: An exception occured while executing the Java class. cucumber.cli.Main -> [Help 1]`

Comment: to what empty entries are you referring? <classpath/>?

Answer (score 2):

According to [exec:java Docs here](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html), you have to :

Remove `<arguments>` part

And use `<additionalClasspathElements>` declarations to define a classpath.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `<classpath/>`, you have to use `exec:exec` and not `exec:java`. You also have to add the executable, which is `java` in your case:

```xml
<executable>java</executable>
```

If I understand it correctly, `exec:java` automatically adds the classpath you cannot override it. The arguments are added after the main class. `exec:exec` is more generic, it executes any executable with any arguments, one of which can be the `<classpath/>`.